# Access parent window control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two windows:

> **ListItemWindow**

(parent) that contain ocItems as ObservableCollection

> **DetailItemWindow**

I called DetailItemWindow from ListItemWindow (DetailItemWindow.ShowDialog())

From DetailItemWindow How can I access to ocItems ?

Comment: Can't you just use this.Parent?

Comment: this.parent always null !

Comment: Possible a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856745/wpf-get-parent-window)...

Comment: When you open a window in WPF the parent isn't automatically set. You have to set it manually between instantiating it and calling .ShowDialog.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, How can I set the parent manually ?

Comment: @m_wilcynski has an answer below that shows how to do it.  It's just a property on the window that you can set before displaying the dialog.  Basically, `OtherWindow.Parent = this` if called from the code behind of a window.  Things get trickier if you are using MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

Why not pass parent Window in constructor to child Window?
It doesn't violate MVVM at all, Views can know each other if they're dependant.

```
private ListItemWindow parent;

public DetailItemWindow(ListItemWindow window){
   this.parent = window;
}
```