# How to add to Click event to Context Menu buttons in WPF NotifyIcon?

Tags: c#, wpf, notifyicon

I am making an app that has a notify icon in WPF. I am using [HardCodet NotifyIcon](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon). They do have a [tutorial on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_notifyicon.aspx) and it is pretty useful but it does not have any explanation on how to set up `OnClick` or `Click` event when the buttons in the context menu are pressed.

I have gone through every property in `NotifyIcon.ContextMenu.Items` and `NotifyIcon.ContextMenu.Items.GetItemAt(i)` (`TaskbarIcon NotifyIcon = (TaskbarIcon) FindResource("MyNotifyIcon")`) but there is nothing I found. I also tried typecasting the buttons to `MenuItem` and using its `Click` event but it didn't help.

This is my `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar">
        <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="MyNotifyIcon"
              ToolTipText="Hello There">
            <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Background="White">
                    <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Settings"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Sign Out"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Help"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I need the buttons to control the `MainWindow` e.g. change the `Visibility` etc..

Comment: do you mean like `<MenuItem Click=...` ?

Comment: @Bizan Thanks but how do I  access this and in which file?

Comment: in `App.xaml.cs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference to other controls, you can just set up a `Click` handler on each `MenuItem`.

```
<MenuItem Header="Open" Click="Open_OnClick"/>
```

In your example, you would implement the event handler in `App.xaml.cs`.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   // ...application code.

   private void Open_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      // ...do something.
   }
}
```

You could also assign a view model as `DataContext` to `TaskbarIcon` and use a command instead.

Comment: Thanks...But when open is clicked I want the visibility of MainWindow to change to Visible I tried `MainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible` but it does nothing...but exit works

Comment: @Garvit13 that's a whole other question, you can [find the window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22856913/366064) but the better approach is to avoid event altogether, and use command instead, so you can easily bind the window visibility to the menu item